# how to dcast pandas dataframe and convert rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have following pandas dataframe

```
 df1
 code  prod  rsp   date_from    date_to      time_from    time_to
 123   MS    75    2018-01-01   2018-01-02   06:00        05:59
 123   HS    65    2018-01-01   2018-01-02   06:00        05:59
 123   MS    76    2018-01-01   2018-01-02   10:00        05:59 
 123   MS    76    2018-01-01   2018-01-02   11:00        05:59 
 123   MS    73    2018-01-02   2018-01-03   06:00        05:59
 123   HS    64    2018-01-02   2018-01-03   06:00        05:59
 123   MS    73    2018-01-02   2018-01-03   10:00        05:59
```

My desired dataframe would be

```
 code   prod   rsp_1  date_from      date_to    time_from_1   time_to_1   rsp_2   time_from_2   time_to_2
 123    MS     75     2018-01-01     2018-01-02   06:00         05:59       76     10:00        05:59
 123    HS     65     2018-01-01     2018-01-02   06:00         05:59        -      -              -              -             -
 123    MS     73     2018-01-02     2018-01-03   06:00         05:59        -      -              -              -             -
 123    HS     64     2018-01-02     2018-01-03   06:00         05:59        -      -              -
```

I am doing following in python

```
L = list(map(tuple,price[['code','prod','date_from']].values))
s = pd.Series(L, index=price.index)
s = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
g = s.groupby(s).cumcount()

df1 = (price.set_index(['code','prod','date_from', s,g])
   .unstack()
   .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
   .reset_index(level=2, drop=True))

   df1.columns = [f'{i}_{j+1}' for i, j in df1.columns]
   df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

I want unique prices `rsp` to be taken into columns. e.g.in `df1` for product `MS` and `date_from` 2018-01-01 there two duplicate entries for `rsp` 76,so we will consider only the first entry. so for 1 product we will have only one date and corresponding price change history.

Comment: Could you explain the desired logic for rsp_2 in relation to rsp_1 ?

Comment: rsp_2 will only come into picture if there are multiple price changes for same product on same day with different rsp's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and then seems solution should be simplied:

```
#by one column
price = price.drop_duplicates('rsp')
#if necessary by multiple columns
#cols = ['code','prod','date_from', 'date_to', 'rsp']
#price = price.drop_duplicates(subset=cols) 

g = price.groupby(['code','prod','date_from', 'date_to']).cumcount()

df1 = (price.set_index(['code','prod','date_from','date_to', g])
            .unstack()
            .sort_index(level=1, axis=1))

df1.columns = [f'{i}_{j+1}' for i, j in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   code prod   date_from     date_to  rsp_1 time_from_1 time_to_1  rsp_2  \
0   123   HS  2018-01-01  2018-01-02   65.0       06:00     05:59    NaN   
1   123   HS  2018-01-02  2018-01-03   64.0       06:00     05:59    NaN   
2   123   MS  2018-01-01  2018-01-02   75.0       06:00     05:59   76.0   
3   123   MS  2018-01-02  2018-01-03   73.0       06:00     05:59    NaN   

  time_from_2 time_to_2  
0         NaN       NaN  
1         NaN       NaN  
2       10:00     05:59  
3         NaN       NaN
```

Comment: seems that for the first line, drop_duplicate by code, prod, date_from, rsp is required (i.e. df.drop_duplicates(subset=['code', 'prod','date_from','rsp'], keep=False) )

Comment: @Kryesec - Thank you, added to solution.

Comment: @jezrael Can we also add `date_from` to the solution?

Comment: oops, sorry... I remove it by accident.

Comment: @jezrael can we do ascending `time`  in `time_from_1`,`time_from_2` and so on.

Comment: @Neil - Do you think sorting by all  `time_to_1, time_to_2, ...` columns?

Comment: Yes. e.g. there are 3 price changes in a day for specific products at `10:00`,`06:30` and `11:30` then `time_to_1` will be `06:30`, `time_to_2` will be `10:00` and `time_to_3` will be `11:30`

Comment: @Neil - My first idea is use `price = price.drop_duplicates('rsp').sort_values('time_from')`,  it working with sample data. But maybe you need sorting by multiple columns in real data - `price = price.drop_duplicates('rsp').sort_values(['code','prod','date_from', 'date_to', 'time_from'])`. problem should be if sorting by multiple columns it sort first by 1. column, then by 2. ... so is possible last sorting is by last column, but not sort by 1., 2. columns... So the best test it with real data.